# What's the purpose of categorizing alternate airdromes?

Tags: faa, icao, rules-of-the-air

Why do we have alternates in categories of take off alternate, enroute alternate and destination alternate. Does this really need to categorize in groups or it's just pointless issue?

Comment: Are you asking for the applicable rules for both ICAO and  the FAA? Or are you asking about the general reason for the use of takeoff/enroute/destination alternates?

Comment: No I'm just asking about categorizing. Why do we need to set alternates in theese three groups?

Comment: https://skybrary.aero/articles/alternate-aerodrome

Comment: I know that definitions completely. I'm asking about the necessity of categorizing them and making them complicated for no reason.

Comment: The elaboration below the definitions make clear why they each exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are categorized because each category (Takeoff alternate, Destination alternate, Enroute alternate) have different rules and procedures (e.g. different weather requirements, etc). If all rules and applicable procedures were the same for all three categories then you would not have to have separate category names.